# How to control usage data of firebase with Blaze price

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es

When I make chatbot by Dialogflow with firebase blaze price,
If some black-user use macro with my chatbot as sending a ton of message,
I have to pay all about that request?
How can I control about this?
I have to check usage data on  real time?

Comment: Your client app should ensure users can't misbehave, because you will pay for the misbehavior. Real time monitoring is non existent, you basically will get notified with a bill attached. Anyway, this is best answered by the Firebase team, get in touch via the support option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not really able to control access to HTTP triggers running on Cloud Functions.  The endpoint is public and everyone can make requests to it.  These accesses will be billed.

If you think there is abusive behavior going to your app, [contact Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/) with your observations and have them investigate.